# Expected coreclr library not found in package graph. Please try running dotnet restore again

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, self-contained

I tried to build the .Net core self contained application for the following RIDs ubuntu.15.04-x64, ubuntu.15.10-x64, and ubuntu.16.10-x64. Then the build is failed with following errors.

> Failed to make the following project runnable: SelfContainedApp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) reason: Expected coreclr library not found in package graph. Please try running dotnet restore again.

But the build and publish of the .Net core self contained application working fine for the RIDs like ubuntu.14.04-x64 and ubuntu.16.04-x64.

What is the problem in this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Below is my .xproj.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>a2b39d97-00e4-4c6d-a734-ccfa6ca1e883</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>SelfContainedApp</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">.\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">.\bin\</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you sure you can build for Linux on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I already built Linux(Ubuntu 14.04) .net core self contained application on a windows machine.

Comment: Can you show your `.csproj`?

Comment: I provided the .xproj. Please find it.